# Reference: Beth Trees in Propositional Logic

Tags: logic, reference-request, propositional-calculus, proof-theory

I am looking for a reference on so-called ''Beth trees''.

Take a finite set of propositional formulas $\mathcal{F}$. As an example, we might be looking for the set of valuations $v$ that satisfy every formula in $\mathcal{F}$. A Beth tree is a type of parse tree that allows us (in a syntactic manner) to find such valuations. A vertical bar separates the formulas we want to be true from the formulas we want to be false. In the case outlined above, we'd write down all formulas of $\mathcal{F}$ to the left of the vertical bar, and the empty set to its right. Then we parse the formulas one by one. Some examples (in the following, $F$ is assumed to be to the left of the vertical bar; some rules would flip for $\lor$/$\land$ when $F$ is assumed to be on the right):

- if $F$ is a propositional variable, we don't do anything as each valuation is uniquely defined by what it does to propositional variables
- if $F$ is $\lnot G$ then $$F, F_1, \ldots, F_n \mid E_1, \ldots, E_m$$ becomes $$F_1, \ldots, F_n \mid G,E_1, \ldots, E_m$$ in a new branch below
- if $F$ is $G \lor H$ then we know that either $G$ or $H$ must be true. So we have two branches so that $$F, F_1, \ldots, F_n \mid E_1, \ldots, E_m$$ becomes $$G,F_1, \ldots, F_n \mid E_1,\ldots ,E_m$$ on one branch and $$H,F_1, \ldots, F_n \mid E_1,\ldots ,E_m$$ on the other
- if $F$ is $G \land H$ then we know that both $G$ and $H$ must be true, so we replace $$F, F_1, \ldots, F_n \mid E_1, \ldots, E_m$$ by $$G,H,F_1, \ldots, F_n \mid E_1,\ldots ,E_m$$ in a new branch below
- if we have a propositional variable $P$ both to the left and to the right of the vertical bar, we can stop as this branch does not give rise to a valuation (we would have $v(P) = 1 = 0$)

Clearly, this is a more visual representation of the method of analytic tableaux. But I have heard the term Beth tree for this type of algorithmic procedure in tree form before -- has anyone seen the term before describing the tree algorithm outlined above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you refer to the original definition of semantic tableaux given by E. W. Beth in *Semantic entailment and formal derivability* (1955), which had been later simplified by R. Smullyan in *First-order logic* (1968) to the widespread definition of semantic tableaux commonly used in logic.

A good reference that traces the introduction and evolution of this tree method for satisfiability and provability is: I.H. Anellis, *[From Semantic Tableaux to Smullyan Trees. A History of the Development of the
Falsifiabitity Tree Method](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rml/1204834539)* (1990).
It contains also a comprehensive bibliography on the topic.

Comment: That resource is brilliant -- thank you!